# Cannot connect PlainText (JSON) to Dataset at Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I uploaded a PlainText file in a JSON format to the new Azure Machine Learning Studio (studio.azureml.net), but I cannot connect the PlainText object with any module. I get all the time the error message "Cannot connect PlainText to Dataset...".

At the documentation ([here](http://help.azureml.net/Content/html/e8219c57-e8dd-4989-9559-bbd73ba5bcea.htm)) is written that "Plain text can be read and then split up into columns with the help of downstream preprocessing modules.", but I can't find any downstream preprocessing modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually Azure ML can't process JSON data. It will probably be added in a future update, but the easiest way (in my opinion) to consume that data is to convert it into CSV format. This can be done quickly with Power Query. Then you upload the CSV file as a new dataset.